# Reporting Services: Can action buttons be added to report?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to have "Accept" and "Reject" buttons on the report for the user to act upon. Accept should execute a stored procedure that does some archiving. Is it doable?

Comment: Are u displaying report in Report Manager only or in something like a ReportViewer control?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: In Report Manager only

Comment: Then you probably can create a dummy subreport, that is getting called on Accept, that subreport would have your stored procedure in the dataset.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter:But how do I trigger action "Accept". I don't see Button in the toolbox.

Comment: It wouldn't be a button, but a TextBox has "Action" which you can set to drilldown to a subreport.

Answer (score 1):

Like Yuriy stated already, there is a workaround with the textbox `Action`. Place a textbox in your report and go to **Text Box Properties > Action**. Here you can use `Go to report` or `Go to URL` as workaround. Now, just put two textboxes in your report and display the text `Accept` and `Reject` and add your action behind it.